# Erro ao passar váriaveis como parametros em powershell

Tags: funções, powershell

Olá

Um script em Powershell tenho o seguinte código:

```
function GetPerfis
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$StartDate,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$EndDate
    )
     $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $cmd.Connection = $conn
    $cmd.Transaction = $transaction

    LogWrite  "GetProfiles startDate: $startDate and endDate: $endDate"

    ....

}

$startDate = $args[0]
$endDate = $args[1]
LogWrite  "startDate: $startDate and endDate: $endDate"
$profiles = GetPerfis -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate
```

Output em log:

```
startDate: 2014-01-01 and endDate: 2015-01-01
GetProfiles startDate: 2014-01-01 and endDate: 2015-01-01
```

Dá me o seguinte erro:

```
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: You cannot call a method on a 
null-valued expression.
```

Alguma ideia o motivo do erro?

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro pode dar em qualquer lado e nao é possível perceber isso sem saber pelo menos o número da linha onde aconteceu.

Será que System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand carregou mesmo? verifique que o $cmd não é $null após esse new-object

dica:

Essa forma de receber paramentros da command line não é nada robusta. $args é estilo de outras linguagens de programaçao e não é nada recomendável em powershell.
em vez de:

```
$startDate = $args[0]
$endDate = $args[1]
```

o que recomendo é que apague essas duas linhas e comece o programa com:

```
param (
   [string]$startDate = "2014-01-01",
   [string]$endDate = "2015-01-01"
)
```

assim sempre é mais fácil inicializar as variaveis que recebe de parametro, e pode logo colocar valor por omissao, que ajuda outros a perceber o que o código espera como parametro.

Comment: Nessa solução aparece me o erro: "The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as 
a variable or a property." Faz ideia do porque?

Comment: Sim, o param() é para colocar antes das restantes instruçoes do ps1.  [https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/how-to-use-parameters-in-powershell/]

Comment: Já coloquei no inicio do script mas continuo com o mesmo erro. Ele dá erro na atribuição do valor default no primeiro parametro...